# I am reading from a file, the if loop or why loop is not picking up the first button "7" but getting all of the rest

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop

I have put lots of output messages to help me to try to follow the code. Everything looks like it is working up until the first time it reads button "7". It immediately goes to button "8".

InputFileAnalyzer() throws Exception {

```
    String expression = null;
    StringTokenizer tokens;
    buttonList = new ArrayList<String>();
    labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
    radioList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create a File instance
    File file = new File("input.txt");

    // Create a Scanner for the file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    // Read a data from a file
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        expression = expression + " " + input.next();
    }
    tokens = new StringTokenizer(expression);

    // lexical and syntax analysis by using StringTokenizer
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {  // hasn't gone thru all the "tokens"
        token = tokens.nextToken();    // get next "token" from input string
        if (token.equals("End.")) {
            break;
        }
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            token = tokens.nextToken();
            if (token.equals("End;")) {
                break;
            } else if (token.equals("Window")) {
                token = tokens.nextToken();
                windowName = token.replaceAll("\"", "");
                token = tokens.nextToken();
                setWindowSize(token);
                token = tokens.nextToken();
                if (token.equals("Layout")) {
                    while (!token.contains(":")) {
                        token = tokens.nextToken();
                        if (token.contains("Flow")) {
                            windowLayout = 0;                           
                        } else if (token.equals("Grid")) {
                            panelLayout = 1;
                            setGridParameters(token);
                        }   
                    }
                }
            } else if (token.equals("TextField")) {
                while (!token.contains(";")) {
                    token = tokens.nextToken();
                    textWidth = Integer.parseInt(token.replaceFirst(";",""));
                }
            } else if (token.equals("Panel")) {
                token = tokens.nextToken();
                while (!token.contains(";")) {
                    token = tokens.nextToken();
                    if (token.contains("Flow")) {
                        panelLayout = 0;
                    } else if (token.contains("Grid")) {
                        panelLayout = 1;
                        setGridParameters(token);
                    }

                }
            } else if (token.equals("Button")) {
                while (!token.contains(";")) {
                    token = tokens.nextToken();
                    buttonList.add(token.replaceAll("\"|;",""));
                }
            } else if (token.equals("Label")) {
                while (!token.contains(";")) {
                    token = tokens.nextToken();
                    labelList.add(token.replaceAll("\"|;",""));
                }
            } else if (token.equals("Group")) {
                token = tokens.nextToken();
                while (!token.contains(";")) {
                    token = tokens.nextToken();
                    radioList.add(token.replaceAll("\"|;",""));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Close the file
    input.close();
```

The button 7 is not showing up at all. Below is the file that I am reading from. Another problem is that it is keeping the first ". I am not sure if that is indicating another problem. Thanks in advance

```
Window "Calculator" (200, 200) Layout Flow:
Textfield 20;
Panel Layout Grid(4, 3, 5, 5):
Button "7";
Button "8";
Button "9";
Button "4";
Button "5";
Button "6";
Button "1";
Button "2";
Button "3";
Label "";
Button "0";
End;
End.
```

This is the setGrid method

```
   public void setGrid(String token){
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(token);
    //System.out.println(token);
    for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++){
        // System.out.println(token + i);
        if(match.find()){
            if(i==0){
                numberOfRows = Integer.parseInt(match.group());
                System.out.println(numberOfRows + " rows " + token);
            }else if(i==1){
                numberOfColumns = Integer.parseInt(match.group());
                System.out.println(numberOfColumns + " col " + token);
            }else if(i==2){
                hGaps = Integer.parseInt(match.group());
                System.out.println(hGaps + " hgap " + token);
            }else{
                vGaps = Integer.parseInt(match.group());
                System.out.println(vGaps + " vgap " + token);
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code reads the token Panel and keeps getting the next one (in a while loop) until it contains a ';' character. This causes the `Button "7";` to be read in the previous block of code. Because the next ';' is in that line.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I tired changing it to ":" but that did not help. I will continue looking into it

Comment: There may be something wrong with my  setGrid(). it is only getting the number of rows. I was attempting to see if I could see exactly where i am losing the "7"